# function results dont match query results php

Tags: php, mysql

EDIT: the responses work well but not quite what i was after i dont think i explained it very well, i just want to return 1 result per function so count how many odd numbers are in the result and count how many even numbers are in the result?

sql fiddle for the data

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfbfa7/1

Im trying to count even and odd numbers by splitting the the results using 2 functions but my results dont match up to the results in the mysql table.

data

```
select number from table group by number

results
1,4,6,7,8,9,11,12
```

function to return odd number count

```
SELECT   
 COUNT(CASE WHEN (number% 2) > 0 THEN number ELSE NULL END) as odd
 FROM test.table
 WHERE date = CURDATE() and time > now() - interval 60 second group by number
 LIMIT 1
```

and the function to return even number count

```
SELECT   
 COUNT(CASE WHEN (number% 2) = 0 THEN number ELSE NULL END) as even
 FROM test.table
 WHERE date = CURDATE() and time > now() - interval 60 second group by number
 LIMIT 1
```

i was hoping the results would be

odd = 4
even = 4

but instead im getting

odd = 8
even = 0

where am i going wrong?

Comment: can you add insert sample data with create table scripts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your query is returning wrong result is probably because you are using `limit 1` try removing it also if you have to use `group by`  use  `group by number` in before you do calculations for this query, i have altered the query here for example.

```
SELECT   
  count(CASE WHEN (a.number% 2) = 0 THEN a.number ELSE NULL END) as even,
  count(CASE WHEN (a.number% 2) <> 0 THEN a.number ELSE NULL END) as odd
FROM (select number from test group by number) a;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfbfa7/22

for the set up you have created im getting 5 even and 5 odd in results, may be you have to recheck the condition you have in where clause if your results are different with actual data.

Comment: that works perfectly thank you how would i go about only pulling in date collected in the past 30 seconds before the query is run i tried to add where date = CURDATE() and time > now() - interval 2 minute

and changed it to (select number,date,time from test group by number) but it returns no results where as if i run it without the adaption it returns results.

Comment: can you try this you should add your condition inside the inline view not outside for example :  `SELECT   
  count(CASE WHEN (a.number% 2) = 0 THEN a.number ELSE NULL END) as even,
  count(CASE WHEN (a.number% 2) <> 0 THEN a.number ELSE NULL END) as odd
FROM (select number from test  where WHERE date = CURDATE() and time > now() - interval 30 second group by number) a;`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like thise.

For even numbers:

```
COUNT(SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE mod(number, 2)=0);
```

For odd numbers:

```
COUNT(SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE mod(number, 2)>0);
```

This will return the only number of odd and even numbers, then collect those numbers with php.

Answer (score 1):

COUNT will add up all the lines it traverses

In your case you must use SUM:

```
 SUM(CASE WHEN (number% 2) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as odd
 SUM(CASE WHEN (number% 2) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as even
```

for simple operations the IF is much cleaner than the CASE:

```
 SUM(IF(number % 2 > 0, 1, 0)) as odd
 SUM(IF(number% 2 = 0, 1, 0)) as even
```

Comment: that works well but how would i go about just returning 1 value to the amount of odd and even numbers in the result e.g. there are 10 numbers 3 even 7 odd so result get returned as odd =7 even = 3 rather than counting the number and showing how many times its present in the table

Comment: Use group by:

 SELECT
     number,
     SUM(IF(number % 2 > 0, 1, 0)) as odd
 FROM test.table
 WHERE 
     date = CURDATE() and time > now() - interval 60 second 
 GROUP BY number

Comment: so if i use group by it returns how many times a value shows in the table e.g.  value's 1,1,1,2,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,7,8,9,10

returns 1/3    2/1   3/1   4/1   5/3   6/1   7/1   8/1   9/1   10/1